# Populate ComboBox of a DataGrid with values from another column

Tags: wpf, validation, data-binding, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am an experienced user of Winforms and I am now playing with WPF, but I am struggling a bit.
I have a datagrid with 2 columns.
The first column is a DataGridTextColumn which is bound to the "Name" property of my object.
The second column is bound to the "Power" property of my object.

When the user edits the Power column, I would like to display a combo box that lists all the Name of the first column in addition of "None" as first item.
How can I do that?

In addition, if the user updates any Name of the first column, I would like the change to be reflected in the Power column. Is it possible?

In code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<MyObject> objects = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dgObjects.ItemsSource = objects;
    }
}

public class MyObject
{   
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Power { get; set; }
}
```

In Xaml:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgObjects" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Power" Binding="????"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Thanks

Comment: You would setup and maintain your collection somewhere else, typically on the same level as what contains the collection of items to bind the datagrid to, and then bind the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` to that collection by changing the `Source` of the binding. In the most common scenario, a `RelativeSource` binding is used to find the parent `DataGrid` and bind to `DataGrid.DataContext.SomeCollection`. For example, `ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.PowerValues, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via binding on the `DataContext`. Though, first you need to set up the Window's `DataContext` properly. `ItemsSource` should not be done via code-behind (this is WPF, use binding!).

Set up your class structure like:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MyObject> Objects { get; } = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Objects.Add(new MyObject
            {
                Name = "Name"
            });
            Objects.Add(new MyObject
            {
                Name = "Name2"
            });
            Objects.Add(new MyObject
            {
                Name = "Name3"
            });
        }
    }

    public class MyObject
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Power { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, update your xaml. You will need to use a `CellTemplate` and a standard `Combobox`. The `ComboBox` will then bind to the Objects collection, display the Name, but set the value in Power.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        x:Name="MyWindow">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="dgObjects" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=DataContext.Objects}" 
                                      DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding Power}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Yes, I'd recommend something like this too although I'd use a `RelativeSource` binding instead of an `ElementName` one depending on the UI hierarchy

Comment: @Rachel are there performance issues/benefits over using RelativeSource?

Comment: It probably is a bit faster to use ElementName instead of traversing up the visual tree, but I don't think it's enough to ever matter. I'm sure someone has done some tests somewhere online if we search :)